# Autogenerating constructor properties with Lombok for Jackson to deserialize when multiple constructors exists

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, lombok

I have an immutable class defined as:

```
@Value
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ImmutableDTO {
     (...)
}
```

Being immutable, I would like to deserialize the JSON that represents through a constructor.
I would like to avoid having to explicitly mark the binding properties with either @ConstructorProperties or @PropertyNames.

1.So first of all I tried to look for a way to do this with Jackson alone, since in other cases, Jackson is smart enough. Adding ParameterNames module on pom.xml and defining the constructor

```
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, onConstructor_= {@JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)})
```

seems futile, for the marking of each property seems to be needed either way.

2.Therefore I looked for a Lombok solution. My favourite approach would have been finding out an explicit annotation that marks a particular constructor for generating the Constructor Properties, but I could not find it

3.As a fallback I relied on the `lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties = true` global lombok.config setting, but then it annotates the properties for both of my constuctors, so I end up with an error: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Conflicting property-based creators:`. I could not find a lombok facility to opt-out a particular constructor from the property marker generation (something like the legacy  `@RequiredArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)`)

So, is there any way to accomplish any of my approaches (by order of preference), or at least any at all?

P.S: I cannot use `@JsonDeserialize(builder = (...))` facility either since my @Builder is precalculating some fields, i.e, using the alternative constructor (that's precisely why I need both, one is for Jackson and the other for manipulation by code (builder), which has calculated fields)

P.S2: I researched the boot option `jackson.mapper.infer_creator_from_constructor_properties: true` but either I am doing something wrong or it is just the explicit feature that otherwise gets autoregistrated when importing `jackson-module-parameter-names` in pom.xml